# Add a line and fix the typo

Tags: matches

My dad has invented a new puzzle genre called “add a line and fix the typo”, but due to his senility I can’t be 100% sure this was a deliberate effort on his part. Last week he showed me a puzzle and I solved it almost instantly.

The puzzle is shown below: you have to make this equation correct by adding a line and fixing the typo.

Note: I tagged this under "matches" even though the equation doesn't really consist of matchsticks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The line can be added here to create an inequality; I doubt this is the intended solution.

[image]

There's a variant of this puzzle in which the solution is 550, where you turn the "5+5" into 545 with the line, but I'm not sure about 500.

Answer (score 2):

Correct solution:

> [image: 545+5=550, not 500]

For those who can't see

> 545+5=550 (the typo is the first 0 being a 5, not a 0.

Comment: Correct answer, well done!

Comment: rot13(Lbh pna nyfb ghea gur frpbaq cyhf fvta vagb n sbhe, engure guna gur svefg bar).

Comment: @EdMurphy, that is indeed the case...